# Send Log/Debug Messages to SharePoint from a clientside ActiveX Component

Tags: 2010, development, .net

I developed a ActiveX Component (C#) for SharePoint 2010 and would like to send log/debug messages to the SP-Server so that they are viewable in the SharePoint LOGS Folder. How am I doing this?

Like the server-side *SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(...)* function. Isn't there any Client-Object-Model function to do this? Or maybe in Javascript, I guess I could call a Script aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620996/Five-suggestions-to-implement-a-better-logging-in

> Suggestion #5 – Utilize diagnostics.asmx web service for the client
>   side applications
>
> It turns out that SharePoint has a /_vti_bin/diagnostics.asmx web
>   service. It has only one method which performs log writing to the ULS
>   with “SharePoint Foundation -> Unified Logging Service” category and
>   “Verbose” level.
>
> If you are crafting Silverlight or JavaScript application, then that
>   web service could be the only way to perform logging which could be
>   accessible by developers or administrators. Other options are quite
>   hard to implement.
>
> SharePoint has lots of Java Script libraries, and it also has
>   functions such as ULSOnError(msg, url, line) and ULSSendException(ex).
>   One does not simple call these functions, so you just need to include
>   additional call ULS.enable with “true” value. Otherwise, you will not
>   get anything at all.
>
> ```
> ULS.enable = true;
> ULSOnError("Hello trace", document.location.href, 0);
> ```

Then you call this JavaScript from your ActiveX Code.